# Network PCI do not show

Tags: drivers, 20.04, vmware, pcie, lspci

I'm trying to run a VM on VMware 6.5 with a ubuntu 20.04 and a 10G interface running as a PCI passthrough, but the adapter does not show in command ip a, for example. Reading a bit, I see that card is recognized as a PCI port. I am thanks for your time.

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
```

but the card is shown on the PCI list

**lspci**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Cavium QLogic 1010/1020/1007/1741 10Gbps CNA (rev 01)
```

**lspci -vv -s 03:00.0**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Cavium QLogic 1010/1020/1007/1741 10Gbps CNA (rev 01)
        DeviceName: pciPassthru0
        Subsystem: Cavium QLogic 1010/1020/1007/1741 10Gbps CNA - LL
        Physical Slot: 160
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
        Region 0: Memory at fd480000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Region 2: Memory at fd4fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=128 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=2 offset=00000000
                PBA: BAR=2 offset=00002000
        Capabilities: [60] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x32, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <64ns
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x32 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
                         10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [a0] Vital Product Data
pcilib: sysfs_read_vpd: read failed: Input/output error
                Not readable
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 40000001 00000c0f df488000 00000000
        Capabilities: [180 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [190 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
                ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 3
                ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
        Kernel driver in use: bna
        Kernel modules: bna
```

**modinfo bna**

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-89-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/brocade/bna/bna.ko
firmware:       ct2fw-3.2.5.1.bin
firmware:       ctfw-3.2.5.1.bin
version:        3.2.25.1
description:    QLogic BR-series 10G PCIe Ethernet driver
license:        GPL
author:         Brocade
srcversion:     340BD6EE75D50B33B0C7100
alias:          pci:v00001657d00000022sv*sd*bc02sc00i*
alias:          pci:v00001657d00000014sv*sd*bc02sc00i*
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           bna
vermagic:       5.4.0-89-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        32:FC:21:6B:C9:30:AA:25:37:10:EF:A4:91:24:FA:7D:37:50:DD:79
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

I really do not know how to continue.

Best,

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 server system?  ((Ubuntu uses *year.month* for *deb* based products & the *year* format for the *snap* only products; so 20 & 20.04 are different products)

Comment: Why do you think that ens192 is *not* your ethernet interface in `ip a`?

Comment: I did not know that about Ubuntu, sorry guiverc. It's Ubuntu 20.04 // Chili555. The VM has two network interfaces. ens192 is one that works at 1G and the PCI card works at 10G

Comment: Please correct your question (*I can then remove my comment(s) too leaving a more inviting question for potential readers).  20 != 20.04